# How to redirect from Audio Output to Mic Input using PulseAudio?

Tags: linux, audio, command-line-interface, maemo, pulseaudio

I'm working on a mobile app for Maemo/MeeGo and Maemo uses PulseAudio. I want to play a mp3 to caller (and cancel the mic when doing it, and not to listen caller, everything should be done on background), to do this, I have to redirect Audio Output from a certain (if not possible, all) app, fake it as a Input and make Phone app use it.

On my Ubuntu PC, I did it with pavucontrol. I created a NULL sink, then:

```
Audio Output (from Amarok) --> to NULL Output 
Skype Input <-- NULL Output
Skype Output --> NULL
```

And It worked, Amarok played the music and It was streaming to Skype, without playing it to me and I didn't hear anything about all process. Problem is;
a) Maemo does not have pavucontrol.
b) Even If it did (or if I package it) It wouldn't be any good since It's a only-GUI app and I have to do all of this stuff on background, without any user input. (mean: CLI or API)

Asked about this on Freenode #pulseaudio and a helpful guy said "It can pretty much be done via pactl or pacmd, the commands you want are move-sink-input and move-source-output, but you need to know device and stream indexes." So It looks like pavucontrol is just a GUI, pactl and pacmd are the real deal, and most importantly, they're CLI apps.

I'm really thankful to him but I don't know anything about "pactl", "pacmd", "move-sink-input" or "device/stream indexes" so I need a very simplified manual page, or a source of similar app, a one-liner command (two? whole page of commands?, just give me them! ^^) or someone with enough patience to explain this stuff to me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The manuals for `pactl` and `pacmd` are readily available if you give it a search.  I found them here:

[pactl](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/pactl.1.html)

[pacmd (pulse-cli-syntax)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man5/pulse-cli-syntax.5.html)

I think you are interested in the following excerpt from the `pactl` manual:

> move-sink-input ID SINK :
>   Move the specified playback stream (identified by its numerical index) to the specified sink (identified by its symbolic name or numerical index).

You should be able to use `pactl list sink-inputs`, `pactl list source-outputs`, `pactl list sinks`, and `pactl list sources` combined with some `grep` and/or `sed` or something of that nature to programmatically determine the correct stream and sink.

Comment: Better late than never? :)