# Raspberry Pi Audio via Ethernet

Tags: audio, raspberry-pi, ethernet

I have an audio extension on two Pi's that allows me to plug in a microphone and a speaker. I want to take microphone input from one Pi and send the audio over an Ethernet cable to the other Pi. The layout of the setup is this:

Smart phone > Aux cable > RPI1 mic input > Ethernet > RP2 audio output > aux cable > speaker

How would I go about doing this from a software perspective? I looked up the SOX software and tried doing it over SSH but can't figure it out.

Comment: What did you configure in SoX? It sounds like you are trying to stream the Microphone input to another device speaker device. Might be able to do this with a links psudeo output device that then transmits the DEV stream. Is this a Ethernet Patch cable or is there a Hub/Switch in place? So many variables.

Comment: Maybe similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4719160/how-to-redirect-from-audio-output-to-mic-input-using-pulseaudio

Comment: Looking over things, using the PulseAudio Sound Server might be a good way to go. It can be managed via CLI using `pactl` and you could setup one PI to be the server (Mic) and then one PI to be the Client (Speaker) over a local network. See more: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/pactl.1.html

Answer (score 0):

Going far afield here, I apologize, but the EVGA Nu audio card has a microphone in jack - you might consider connecting to a pc with your mic for hi-fi results, and sending out from there to pi via Ethernet. This would obviously be moving pretty far out of the pi ecosystem, but if getting sound out thru a pi is your goal...